# Typescript: cannot create property inside function

Tags: function, syntax, properties, typescript

I'm using TypeScript in my project and i am not able to assign a property to anything.  I'm attempting to grab some data from a service and assign it to a private object declared using the constructor.  However, i keep getting the same error: TypeError: Cannot create property [some property here] on [some data here].
Here's my code:

```
module MyModule.Controllers {
    "use strict";

    export interface ICurrentUser {
        DisplayName: string;
        Features: string[];
    }

    export class DashboardController  {
        authenticationService = new Services.AuthenticationService(this.$http);
        static $inject = ["$http"];

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private currentUser: ICurrentUser, private currentUserFeatures: string[])
        {
            this.getCurrentUser();
            this.getUserGroupForCurrentUser();
            return;
        }

        getUserGroupForCurrentUser = () => {
            this.authenticationService.getUserGroupForCurrentUser().then((authenticationId) => {
                this.currentUser.Features = authenticationFeatures;
           });
        }

       getCurrentUser = () => {
           this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser().then((user) => {
               this.currentUser.DisplayName = userName;
           });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: need the actual error that you are getting

Comment: TypeError: Cannot create property 'DisplayName' on string 'John Doe'

Comment: I can't figure it out. It seems like `this.currentUser.DisplayName = userName;` is the source of the problem though. Perhaps `this.currentUser` is not the `ICurrentUser` object and is something else because it in a promise?

Comment: private currentUser: ICurrentUser means the return type HAS to be ICurrentUser.

Comment: No it does not. Interfaces do not create any JavaScript, so there is no runtime enforcement. You can still pass any type of variable into the constructor. You'll get a compile time error if you try it in TypeScript, it can still generate the JavaScript though. You'll get no error if you try it in JavaScript. My guess is that Chris is right. You accidentally passed a string in. Also, I don't see where `userName` is coming from on that same line in question.

Comment: @user1789573 Are you absolutely sure of that? TypeScript only checks the types at compile time, but there might be some badly written code that causes `currentUser` not to be an `ICurrentUser` at run time? Try placing a breakpoint on the `this.currentUser.DisplayName = userName;` and check what `this.currentUser` *really* holds.

Comment: this.currentUser is undefined, like i would expect. Right? Should i expect that it would be an empty object because of the private access modifier on the object in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot create property 'DisplayName' on string 'John Doe' –

This is on the following code:

```
this.currentUser.DisplayName = userName;
```

Seems that at runtime `this.currentUser` is actually a *string* `John Doe`. This points to the fact that the type *declarations* (which are effectively hints to the compiler about external systems not in its control) do not match the actual external system at runtime.